# Enabling secure boot disables one of two monitors?

Tags: boot, secure-boot

I have a dual boot machine with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 21.04, I have just been in the BIOS enabling Secure Boot and TPM for a future Windows 11 update.

Ubuntu boots with TPM & Secure Boot enabled but I only get 1 of 2 displays to work with Secure Boot.  I've checked in the display settings and I have the latest NVIDIA (GT 1030) driver installed.

What could be the problem and what is the remedy?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you signed the Nvidia drivers before, by enabling Secure Boot it automatically prevented the drivers from loading so what you're running right now is nouveau instead and that's why the support for extra features like external connections / multiple monitors simply isn't there.

Comment: thanks , I will look into that